# How can I convert an Int into an enum?

Tags: swift, enums

How do I convert an arbitrary Int into an enum?

Here's the enum:

```
enum contributeButtonType:Int {
    case plusSign = 0
    case textResponse
    case video
    case photo
     func selectedMediumName() -> (String) {
        switch self {
        case .textResponse:
            return("Text")
        case .video:
            return("Video")
        case .photo:
            return("Photo")
        default:
            return("Unknown")
        }
    }
}
```

I'm trying to convert an Int parameter into its equivalent enum for processing:

```
func getMedium(#sender:UIViewController, #mediumType:Int) {
    let myMedium = mediumType as mediumEnumType
    let mediumDesc = myMedium.selectedMediumName()
}
```

What I get is the following compiler error: 
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You use initializer syntax passing in the raw value of the enum.

```
let myMedium = contributeButtonType(rawValue: mediumType)
```